# Normal members of the group without any admin rights cannot see the facebook post done through an in-development facebook app. How can i make them?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I have followed a tutorial through which i have managed to post on a facebook group using their sdk and graph API on python, on the graph api version 11.

1. I created a user on facebook, gave it the admin rights of that particular group.
2. Created an app on facebook, in development mode.
3. Requested permissions through that app for posting to the relevant group as that user.
4. Generated extended access token for the same.

Issue: Admins of the group can see the posts, but the normal members of the group cannot.
is it an issue with the app? Does it need to be out of development for the posts created by it to be made visible to others?

Python Code snippet:

```
import json
from facebook import GraphAPI

access_token= 'access token here'
 
graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
 
message = 'This is a test post...hear me'
link = '' #link needs to go here
groups = ['group id here'] #group id
 
for group in groups:
    graph.put_object(group,'feed', message=message,link=link)
    print(graph.get_connections(group, 'feed'))
```

[image: Permissions]

[image: App Dashboard]

Comment: Yes the app needs to be out of development I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mentioned in facebook's documentation.
Whenever an app is created on facebook's developer console, in developer mode, any posts made by the app are not seen by the general public even if you are posting on public groups. Depending on the permissions and what you are trying to accomplish exactly, you might need to go through app review and through business review.
If you don't need to go through the reviews for the permission you have chosen, make sure that the app is in "Live" mode and you will be good to go.
handy feature if they were a bit upfront about it.